# Deleting specific row in 2D arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to delete a specific row from 2D arraylist and that row is replaced by the next row. I wrote following code:

`Collection<?> c = joint_mat.get(row);
  joint_mat.get(row).removeAll(c);`

This code is deleting the elements of the row but not replacing it with the next row. Output is as follows:

[0.6, 0.608, 0.608, 0.628, 0.608],

[0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.608, 0.608],

[0.6, 0.652, 0.6, 0.612, 0.608],

**[],**

[0.612, 0.632, 0.608, 0.604, 0.608],

[0.6, 0.604, 0.604, 0.62, 0.62],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
joint_mat.remove(row);
```

P.S. an easier way to do what you are doing above, clearing the contents of the arraylist on the row, is like this:

```
joint_mat.get(row).clear();
```

Comment: joint_mat.get(row).clear(); is working as same. I want to remove entire row.